# i'm getting ") expected and } expected while i checked everything and it should work?

Tags: c#

i'm a very beginner programmer (c#) but im getting a weird error: ") expected" and "} expected". I checked the code and it should work? The program i was making was just to get a little familiar with coding and its a very simple login with the console code. It also isn't that clean yet but i just couldn't find the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
 bool newAccount = false;
 newLogin = false;
 string username2;
 string password2;

  start:
    Console.Clear();
   
    // a bool wich its default value is set to false
    bool searching = false;
    bool login = true;
    bool Again = false;
    bool waiting = false;
    
    // says enter your username 
     Console.WriteLine ("Enter username here:");
    
    // stores the username

  string Username = Console.ReadLine();

    // displayes the username
    Console.WriteLine($"\nYour username is now: {Username}");
    
    // says enter your password
    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your password here:");
    
    // Gets Password of the user
    string Password = Console.ReadLine();

    // displays the password and username of the user
    Console.WriteLine($"\nYour password is now: {Password}. And your username is now: {Username}.");
    
    goback:
// Login code 
Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your username now:");
if (Username == Console.ReadLine()) {
  Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your password now:");
  if (Password == Console.ReadLine()) {
    Console.WriteLine("Yes, You logged in!");
    login = false; 
}
else {
 Console.WriteLine("Oops! Loggin failed, have you typed in the right password and username?");
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
 Console.Clear();
 goto goback;
}
}
 //if password or username is wrong it shows this
else {
  Console.WriteLine("Oops! Loggin failed, have you typed in the right password and username?");
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  Console.Clear();
  goto goback;
}
 //if you succesfully logged in then this will appear
if (login == false) {
  Console.WriteLine("\nLogin succesfull you can search now! Lets type the first question by typing lesson1");


 //this code makes other code wait
   Console.WriteLine("Warning! the console is about to be cleared. 3...");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("2...");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("1...");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("Clearing console...");
Thread.Sleep(750);
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Search by typing in the console:");
}
  
  back:
  string search = Console.ReadLine();
searching = true;

// the search engine
if (login == false) {
  switch (search) {

    case "show account 1":
    Console.WriteLine($"\nUsername: {Username}");
    Console.WriteLine("Want to show password? y/n | if you want to hide type clear.");
    if (Console.ReadLine() == "y") {
    Console.WriteLine($"Password: {Password}");
    }
    goto back;
    break;

    case "show account 2": 
    goto NewAcc;
    newLogin = true;
    break;

    case "create new account":
    goto start;
    break;

    case "create second acc":
    goto newAcc;
    break;

    case "create second account":
    Console.WriteLine("Seccond account is getting created...");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.Clear();
    newAccount = true;
    goto newAcc;
    break;
    
    case "log out":
    goto goback;
    break;
    
    case "clear": 
  Console.WriteLine("Warning! the console is about to be cleared. 3...");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("2...");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("1...");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("Clearing console...");
Thread.Sleep(750);
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Search by typing in the console:");
goto back;
break;
    
    case "lesson 1": 
    Console.WriteLine("\nSo you want to see lesson 1? well in that case it was about variables");
    goto back;
    break;
    
    case "lesson 2": 
    Console.WriteLine("\nwell have you heard about Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine? and if you finish a code sentence always use: ;");
    goto back;
    break;

    default: 
    Console.WriteLine("\nNo matches found, try to search something different?");
    goto back;
    break;
  }
}
newAcc:

// second account
while (newAccount) {
if (newAccount == true) {
  Console.WriteLine("Enter second username:");

  username2 = Console.ReadLine();

  Console.WriteLine("Enter second password:");

  password2 = Console.ReadLine();

  Console.WriteLine("New account created!");
  newAccount = false;
  goto back;
}
}

NewAcc:
Console.WriteLine("login| username:");
while (newLogin) {
  if (newLogin == true;) {
  if (username2 == Console.ReadLine()) {
  Console.WriteLine("Password:");
  if (password2 == Console.ReadLine()) {
    Console.WriteLine("Succesefull login!");
    if (search == "show account 2") {
      Console.WriteLine($"Your username is {username2}. \nDo you want to show your password? y/n| you can clear all this at anytime by typing clear.");
      if (search == "y") {
        Console.WriteLine("password2");
        goto back;
      }
    }
  }
  }
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately you've posted nearly 200 lines of code, without formatting it (in terms of indentation), and told us what the error is but not given us any indication of *where* it is. That makes it much harder for us to help you than if you could provide a [mcve] with clear details.

Comment: The errors aren't weird. Your code has errors. You didn't post the actual compilation error which would point you directly to the line that fails. This code, with all those `goto` is a maintenance nightmare and as you found out, hard to even write correctly. You don't need all that code just to read a couple of inputs

Comment: I'd also *strongly* advise you to a) start following .NET naming conventions; b) avoid using `goto`.

Comment: Break your code into separate methods too. Right now, nobody can tell what this code does, with execution jumping all over the place. If you have to use a comment to explain what a section of code does, you should probably extract that section into a separate method

Comment: the best practice about using goto: ***don't***

Comment: Please don't use `goto` please use loops and break your code in to separate methods.

Comment: WARNING: `goto` used in code. Minus 10 points for Gryffindor.

Answer (score 1):

Change in the bottom part of your code in the while loop

```
if (newLogin == true;) {
```

change that to

```
if (newLogin == true) {
```

Comment: Thanks! i changed the code and i'm not gonna use gotos in the future, and i started to implement methods.

Comment: @MatDePatatDini Glad to hear it. I can recommend reading this tutorial for OOP https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/object-oriented-programming-using-C-Sharp-net/